# How to make content start in the middle/top instead of the bottom?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using this javascript to make images scroll vertically from the bottom till the top, but I can't figure out how to make the images start scrolling when the frame is filled. Right now it's empty when the site/script loads, and I'd like to change that.

Thank you! (I'm sorry for the long code)

Here's the code:

```
<script>

step = 1
nextMessage = 1

counter = 20;

function initTSV1() {
    tsvDisplay = document.getElementById("tsvcont")

    for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        newDiv = document.createElement("DIV")
        newDiv.setAttribute("id", "tsvdiv" + i)

/*newDiv.onmouseover=function(){
    clearTimeout(timer);
    counter = 40;
}

newDiv.onmouseout=function(){
    counter = 20;
    scrollTSV1();
}*/

        newDiv.style.position = "absolute"
        newDiv.style.padding = "0 5 0 10" // top right bottom left
        tsvDisplay.appendChild(newDiv)
    }

    tsvDv0 = document.getElementById("tsvdiv0")
    tsvDv1 = document.getElementById("tsvdiv1")
    tsvDv0.innerHTML = info[0]
    tsvDv1.innerHTML = info[1]

    tsvDv0.style.top = tsvDisplay.offsetHeight
    tsvDv1.style.top = tsvDisplay.offsetHeight + tsvDv0.offsetHeight + "px"

    scrollTSV1()
}

function scrollTSV1() {

/*$("#tsvcont").mouseover(function() {
    counter = 40;

}).mouseout(function() {
    counter = 20;
});*/


    $("#tsvcont").mouseout(function() {
        counter = 20;
    }).mouseover(function() {
        counter = 40;
    });



    tsvDv0Pos = parseInt(tsvDv0.style.top)
    tsvDv1Pos = parseInt(tsvDv1.style.top)

    tsvDv0Pos -= step
    tsvDv1Pos -= step

    tsvDv0.style.top = tsvDv0Pos + "px"
    tsvDv1.style.top = tsvDv1Pos + "px"

    if (tsvDv0Pos < -tsvDv0.offsetHeight) {

        nextMessage++
        if (nextMessage == info.length) {
            nextMessage = 0
        }
        tsvDv0.innerHTML = info[nextMessage]

        if (tsvDv1.offsetHeight < tsvDisplay.offsetHeight) {

            if (tsvDv1.offsetTop < tsvDisplay.offsetHeight - tsvDv1.offsetHeight) {
                tsvDv0.style.top = tsvDisplay.offsetHeight + "px"
            }
            else {
                tsvDv0.style.top = tsvDv1.offsetTop + tsvDv1.offsetHeight + "px"
            }

        }
        else {
            tsvDv0.style.top = tsvDv1.offsetTop + tsvDv1.offsetHeight + "px"
        }

    }

    if (tsvDv1Pos < -tsvDv1.offsetHeight) {

        nextMessage++
        if (nextMessage == info.length) {
            nextMessage = 0
        }
        tsvDv1.innerHTML = info[nextMessage]

        if (tsvDv0.offsetHeight < tsvDisplay.offsetHeight) {

            if (tsvDv0.offsetTop < tsvDisplay.offsetHeight - tsvDv0.offsetHeight) {
                tsvDv1.style.top = tsvDisplay.offsetHeight + "px"
            }
            else {
                tsvDv1.style.top = tsvDv0.offsetTop + tsvDv0.offsetHeight + "px"
            }

        }
        else {
            tsvDv1.style.top = tsvDv0.offsetTop + tsvDv0.offsetHeight + "px"
        }

    }

    timer = setTimeout("scrollTSV1()", counter);

}

// add onload="initTSV1()" to the opening BODY tag

</script>

<style>

#tsvcont{
    position:relative;
    width:290px;          /* width = target width - (border * 2) */
    height:500px;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-align:left;
}

#tsvdiv0 {
    position:absolute;
    width:290px;          /* width = tsvcont width - ((border + padding) * 2) */
    padding:0px 0px 30px 0px;
    height:600px;

}
#tsvdiv1{
    position:relative;
    width:290px;          /* width = tsvcont width - ((border + padding) * 2) */
    padding:30px 5 0px 5;
    height:600px;

    }
</style>


</HEAD>
<BODY onLoad="initTSV1()">
<DIV id="tsvcont" style="position:relative; width:290px; height:500px; overflow:hidden; text-align:left; left: 50px";></DIV>
```

Comment: on stack you should select one answer to your questions as `accepted` that way on future questions people would be more inclined to help ^_^

Comment: Thank you man :) I've done this now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of placing the function in the body unload, since **you are using jQuery**

try this:

```
$(function(){
   initTSV1();
});
```

put that somewhere in a script

Comment: I don't really understand where to put it, since there's already a <code>function initTSV1(){
tsvDisplay=document.getElementById("tsvcont")</code>

Could you explain it a little further please? :)

Thank you

Comment: Neal's code is a call to the `function initTSV1()` function. IIRC, `$(function(){...}` is basically shorthand for `document.ready()`. In other words, it calls `initTSV1()` after the page has fully loaded and is ready to go.

Comment: Thank you Shauna, but I still don't know where to put the code. I'm not familiar with jquery. Should I call the code with <script type="javascript">
$(function(){
   initTSV1();
});
</script>

or should I put this in the function come somewhere?

Comment: @Jaoza - You can put it in its own script tag, if you want (though I'd limit doing that to really simple stuff, that function can get really long, really quickly if you have a lot of JS going on). I generally have a master .js file that holds most of my custom stuff, and put it at the top of it.

Comment: @Shauna thank you for your help, but I have to ask you to explain further, since I don't know exactly where we are right now :)

So, the original code (the long code that I started this thread with), what needs to be done with it? Is it enough if I add the code Neal wrote in the beginning of the script or should I replace something? I don't really get it since I don't really understand how the script works. Thank you for your understanding.

Comment: @Neal can't really say, a friend of mine sent this to me when I had problems with another jquery scroller, I can't find any credits for it.

Comment: @Jaoza i ask because it is a bad mix of plain javascript and jquery. what is it supposed to do?

Comment: @Neal haha too bad I don't understand it, but it definately looks messy :P The thing is that it's a text/image scroller for which I'm using as a vertical image scroller. It's height is 500 and the images start scrolling upwards when the site is loaded. I want the script to load the images so the frame is filled when the site is loaded. If you do not understand I cant write the url :)

Comment: @Neal looks great! The only thing that needs to be changed with that code is that I don't want the scrolling to end. I want it to keep scrolling so that when the last image is shown the first will reload. Is this possible?

Comment: @Jaoza, yes that is deff possible, ill change the fiddle a bit, one min

Comment: @Neal thank you very much for your help! I wish I could give you "thumbs up" but I do not have enough reputation :/ But thank you very much!

Comment: @Jaoza, this is taking me longer then expected please wait :-p

Comment: @Jaoza, this version restarts after it goes all the way thru http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/xw6dT/

Comment: its a little slow, need to play around with the timers

Comment: @Neal thank you very much but it goes empty also, is there a way to make 2 sections loop? I really appreciate your effort.

Comment: it goes blank but then starts up again about 2 seconds later

Comment: @Neal yeah it's almost perfect! It's just that one of the guys who're gonna use this site requires the script to reload the images before the frame is empty. Is it difficult to make?

Comment: I can't get the java you've written to work. I've put the css in style.css and the java code in "scroll.js", but how to I get it to start?

<script type="javascript" src="scroll.js"></script> Is this enough?

Comment: @Jaoza - Do you have a call to the jQuery core somewhere? There should be a line in your HTML of something along the lines of `<script type="javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>` (or wherever you're referencing jQuery core from, I recommend the Google library - http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/devguide.html#jquery), somewhere before the call to Neal's script.